# How to "hardcode" a shapefile's CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I am using some shapefiles in an agent-based model I am developing using [MASON](https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/) (a Java-based modeling framework). All the shapefiles I am using have a **EPSG: 27700 OSGB 1936/British National Grid** CRS.

I have just started to test my model using a different study area and the model is visualising the shapefiles with a different CRS to what appears in QGIS/ArcGIS.

The shapefiles are clipped from the same larger shapefiles that I have used for the other study areas and those display as expected using EPSG: 27700.

I've been told that:

> GeoMason is "blind" to the CRS. It simply imports the geometric
>   character of each feature, disregarding projections and whatnot. There
>   is no problem with this approach, you just have to make sure every
>   data set you feed to a particular simulation refers to a single CRS.
>
> GeoMason exports rasters and vectors without setting CRS information,
>   although it is tacitly the same CRS as the input data. A pasteriori
>   you might hardcode the CRS yourself using a tool like GDAL/OGR (note
>   that this is not possible for certain formats like ArcGRID).

I have no idea how to "hardcode" the CRS myself and have never used GDAL/OGR and only have limited Python experience.

[image: Shapefiles with correct CRS as displayed in QGIS]

[image: Model output with different CRS]

Comment: If this were 1987 or 1992, it would be excusable for a modeling tool to ignore coordinate references. By 1997 it would have been harder to make that argument. Twenty years after *that*, there really isn't any excuse for ignoring, much less stripping the .prj from input data.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your output? It looks different than it does in QGIS but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's wrong. If your modeling software requires all your shapefiles to be in the same CRS, and yours are, it seems like it's working.

Comment: double-check your shapefile, this 'squishing' would be expected if the original shapefile is in degrees (e.g. WGS84). It's not enough to use On-the-fly projection. Also, try re-sizing the MASON window. It may be that tool simply fits the output into the window's frame.

Comment: @StevenKay Oh my gosh! You were right. I was reusing code for my previous case study and I had not updated the GUI and so it was 'squishing' the visualisation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to **disable** On-the-fly-reprojection in QGIS. If the data looks good then, it works ok with Mason too.

And make sure to switch `Settings -> Options -> CRS`, `CRS for new layers` to `Prompt for CRS` to avoid unwanted CRS assignment.

Comment: The simple way in QGIS is to set the correct CRS in the layer settings, or to set a standard CRS  according to your needs as AndreJ described. Gdal_translate is relatively easy to use from the commandline.